# Qt5 qmake - A suitable version of Python 2 could not be found

Tags: python, compiler-errors, qt5

My aim is to build QtWebEngine from source, and the following steps are what I have done in order to try and achieve this. I am getting an error about Python 2 not being able to be found.

What I have installed so far:

- `Qt5.12.6` (from their online installer - `source`, `msvc2017`, `msvc2017_64`, `msvc2015`, `qtwebengine`)
- `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019` (from their website)
- `Python 2.7.17` & `Python 3.8.0` (2.7.17 to compile parts of Qt, 3.8.0 for general coding - both from `python.org`)

I need to rebuild the `QtWebEngine` from source, and to do this I am following these steps by typing the following into the `CMD` and hitting the enter key after each bullet point:

- `cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build"`
- `vcvars64.bat`

The output from this command is:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.2.0
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
```

- `cd \`
- `cd Qt\5.12.6\Src\qtwebengine`
- `"C:\Qt\5.12.6\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" -- -webengine-proprietary-codecs`

The output from this final bullet point is:

```
Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... no
  Full debug information ................. no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
  Printing and PDF ....................... yes
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... yes
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. yes
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... yes
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ yes

WARNING: Python version 2 (2.7.5 or later) is required to build QtWebEngine.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'nmake'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'nmake install'.
Qt will be installed into 'C:\Qt\5.12.6\msvc2017_64'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.


A suitable version of python2 could not be found.
QtWebEngine will not be built.
```

I have installed Python 2.7.17 from python.org, and its file location is `C:\Python27`.
The filepaths:

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\scripts
```

are both in the `PATH`, in that order. I also have the 2 `Python 3.8.0` folders (same as above) stored in `PATH`, above the `Python 2.7.17` folders.
I am running on `Windows 10 (64 bit)`

What is it that I must do so that `Python 2.7.17` can be recognised by `Qt5.12.6` when I try to build `QtWebEngine`?

Comment: add python.exe to PATH

Comment: Cant add an exe to PATH, only folders cant I?

Answer (score 1):

Remove Python 3.8.0 from PATH.
refer https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html
Following is mentioned on official Qt documentation
"
On all platforms, the following tools are required:

Python 2.7.5 or later. Python 3 is not supported.
Bison, Flex
GPerf
Windows
On Windows, the following additional tools are required:

Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 or later
Windows 10 SDK
Qt WebEngine can only be built on 64-bit Windows, with a x64-bit toolchain. For building Qt WebEngine for x86 applications, you need to configure and compile Qt with the Visual Studio 2017 x64 to x86 cross-compile toolchain. This toolchain can be set up on the command line by running vcvarsall.bat amd64_x86.
"

Note: In Qt 5.15 build requirement its mentioned that
Use Python 2.7.5 or later. Python 3 is not supported.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. Search for 'executing config test webengine-python2' in `config.log` in your qt5 repository to get more details. Open CMD and additionally check your pyhon2.exe/python.exe locations via:

```
where python2
where python
```

**Only one of these two must be set!** 'python2' is sometimes used to avoid name conflicts.

Maybe `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` or Python 3 hides your [Python 2.7.5+](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installation. You can fix that, reordering the entries of your `PATH` environment variable. Put your two Python 2 installation folders above 'WindowsApps' and 'python3' folders. Instead of modifying your `PATH` environment variable you can also set them in CMD temporary to the front:

```
set PATH=C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;%PATH%
```

After doing so, make a clean checkout or cleanup your current qt5 repository, because for me the cache of qmake was not updated by reconfiguration:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"
git clean -dfx
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the python path correctly, you also need to clear all config cache files.

You can detect these cache files according to ctime of files in `qtwebengine` folder. For example:
[image]

Comment: This answer adds something useful but does not answer fully the original question. To avoid getting downvotes, instead of posting your comment as a new answer, please consider adding a comment to an existing answer or to suggest an edit to an existing answer.